# clear formatting from document

Tags: html, css

I get a lot of text that I have to put in a Joomla editor. I am so tired of cleaning the formatting on the text, because it is made in Google docs. I startet to make a CSS file to style the text. But is there a html or CSS command, that can clean the formatting, when some text is copied from an editor to another?

Comment: Is there not an option to paste unformatted text?

Comment: The only way you can do it, as far as I know is to copy the text from the document, paste it to the editor and then remove the formatting. It is not a big problem, but at the office we maybe have to do it 100 times a day. It could just be so much easier if the text could be copied, and you could start style the text immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "Paste as plain text", for example in Chrome its <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.

If that is what you were asking.

Comment: Hello C14L. Thank you for the answer. That is actually what I am using now. But actually I just realized that you cannot do what I am asking. No html or CSS script is of course runned, because I copy some text over in an editor. I will keep on doing the ctrl shift v :)